# The server was not found or was not accessible - Server was lost for 6 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2008

First off, I only have a very basic understanding of SQL. I can create tables etc. but configuration is beyond me. I am running my web site with MVC3 ASP.Net on a windows 2008 server using SQL Express.

Everything works fine, my connection strings are correct, I can use the website and it reads and writes to the dB, I can also view the dB with management studio on the server.

Today I got the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

When I tried to log on to the database in management studio on the server I get a similar error. the only fix I have found is for a server restart. The database was down for 6 hours before I noticed which is not good for a start up website.

Has any one seen this issue before? Is this an express issue? Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: How many servers are we talking about here? Web site on one server, SQL Server on a second server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshoot as you would any network error. Start with the server's event logs.

As for notification of downtime, there are a lot of web services that will monitor your web site and email or send you an SMS message if it's not responding. Two that I've used are [uptimerobot.com](http://uptimerobot.com/) and [basicstate.com](http://basicstate.com/). There are dozens of others.

You could also rewrite your ASP.Net app to email or text you when certain kinds of errors happen.

Comment: Thanks, will defo look at the bots. I will have a look at the event logs and see if i can find anything there